# Utilizar una dependencia de node_modules en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm

estoy utilizando laravel 9, tengo webpack de laravel mix y estaba intentando utilizar la librería [virtual select](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=get-started)

sin embargo, tengo un problema, no puedo incluirla luego de instalarla, he intentado lo siguiente

he abierto el archivo webpack.mix.js y he añadido la libería de npm pero me da error

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('virtual-select-plugin')  //he añadido la librería desde aquí
    ]);
```

y a la hora de hacer `npm run dev` obtengo el error
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'virtual-select-plugin'

> Require stack:
>
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\webpack.mix.js
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
> - C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js

y si lo borro y lo hago de la siguiente manera:
abriendo el archivo `resources/js/app.js` y añadiendo esto:

```
import {VirtualSelect} from "virtual-select-plugin/src/virtual-select";
window.VirtualSelect = VirtualSelect;
```

compila correctamente, pero luego no puedo iniciarla desde el script con:

```
VirtualSelect.init({
    ele: '#area-group-select',
    options: myOptions,
    multiple: true,
    search: true,
    placeholder: "{{__('Select Picked Orders')}}",
    noOptionsText: "{{__('No results found')}}",
});
```

obtengo en la consola el error: Uncaught ReferenceError: VirtualSelect is not defined

cómo puedo usar la librería?

Comment: usa:  import VirtualSelect from "virtual-select-plugin/src/virtual-select";
window.VirtualSelect = VirtualSelect;------ y verifica que tu ruta sea corecta en el node_modules, no hagas cambios en webpack.mix.js, todos los modulos debrian cargarse en app.js

Comment: esos requires del webpack.mix.js son plugins de tailwindcss. No toques eso!